# Laravel - function failed() in Job

Tags: laravel

I am trying to process a failed job in my class.

An error occurs when executing this handle() code. Accordingly, an entry appears in the failed_jobs table. It's all good. Some code is executed here, which leads to an error and, accordingly, leads to the failure of the job.

public function failed() //****HERE I want to get the job_id which is failed.

Here is the code

**JOB**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use 

class ProcessResult implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $id;
    private $authUserId;

    public function __construct($id, $authUserId)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->authUserId = $authUserId;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @param $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
      //Some code is executed here, which leads to an error and, accordingly, leads to the 
        failure of the job.
    }

public function failed() //****HERE I want to get the job_id which is failed.
    {
        // Called when the job is failing...
        Qprogress::where('queue_id', $this->job->getJobId())
            ->update(['qstatus' => 'job is failed' . $exception]);
    }
```

**AppServiceProvider**

...

```
public function boot()
    {
        Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
            // $event->connectionName
            // $event->job
            // $event->exception
            Log::error('Oops, it did not work again...' . $event->job->getJobId ()); //Here is all is ok
        });
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this failed method.

```php
use Throwable;

public function failed(Throwable $exception)
{
   Log::error('Failed job ID: ' . $this->job->getJobId());
}
```

Comment: local.ERROR: Call to a member function getJobId on null and with parentheses getJobId() error to...

Comment: Can you try this: `Log::info($this->job);`